# Gitlab CI/CD workflow rule variables only allow one if condition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to structure my .gitlab-ci.yml file like following:

- There is one pipeline called "a" which should run only from the develop branch
- There is one pipeline called "b" which should run only from the develop branch but only when triggered from the web

In order to avoid putting these rules in the jobs directly (in reality there are about 30 jobs) I want to reuse those rules globally. I could not find a better way other than using workflow:rules.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
        RUN_A: "true"
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      variables:
        RUN_B: "true"

job-a:
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_A == "true"
  script:
    - exit 0

job-b:
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_B == "true"
  script:
    - exit 0
```

The problem is, that if there is a web trigger on develop, it will not set "RUN_B" to `true`. It will just have "RUN_A" with `true`. I added another job to print out the variables just to make sure:

```
test:
  image: alpine
  script:
    - echo $RUN_A
    - echo $RUN_B
```

This will only print `true` for RUN_A but nothing for RUN_B. I could not find anything in Gitlabs documentation that states it will only use the first matching rule. Anyhow, is there a better way to handle this? What am I missing?

Comment: For everyone else who ends up here through $SEARCH_ENGINE: Since December 2022 there has been [a Gitlab bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/341091) that effectively prevents usage of multiple variables (like in the question & accepted answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because GitLab ci `Rules` evaluated in order until the **first** match.

in your first rule `if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"` is match, the pipeline is create, in this times variable `RUN_A: "true"` is set, but variable `RUN_B` is undefined.

In your case, you can modify your .gitlab-ci.yml. variable setting and rules order.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      variables:
        RUN_B: "true"
        RUN_A: "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
        RUN_A: "true"

default:
  image: alpine

job-a:
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_A == "true"
  script:
    - exit 0

job-b:
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_B == "true"
  script:
    - exit 0

test:
  script:
    - echo $RUN_A
    - echo $RUN_B
```